# grid layout and cardview not showing anything, android studio

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-cardview, android-gridlayout

while using grid layout and cardview it shows only white rectangle not even divided on my phone while working fine on the emulator, adding pics so you could see exactly what I'm talking about;

on the emulator it looks like this: pic from emulator

[image]
and on my phone it looks like this: pic from my phone:

[image]

this is the xml:

```xml
<RelativeLayout
            android:layout_below="@+id/layoutGrid"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/space"
            android:background="#000036"/>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/layoutMore"
            android:layout_below="@+id/space"
            android:background="#000036">
            <GridLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:rowCount="1"
                android:columnCount="3"
                android:columnOrderPreserved="false"
                android:alignmentMode="alignMargins">
                <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    android:layout_row="0"
                    android:layout_column="0"
                    app:cardElevation="6dp"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
                    android:layout_margin="12dp">
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:padding="16dp"
                        android:layout_row="0"
                        android:layout_column="0"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:background="#126180"
                        android:id="@+id/layoutSettings">
                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="80dp"
                            android:layout_height="80dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/baseline_settings"/>
                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Settings"
                            android:textColor="@color/white"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
                <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    app:cardElevation="6dp"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
                    android:layout_margin="12dp"
                    android:background="#000036">
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:padding="16dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:background="#000036"
                        android:id="@+id/layoutReports">
                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="80dp"
                            android:layout_height="80dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/baseline_square"/>

                    </LinearLayout>
                </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
                <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    app:cardElevation="6dp"
                    android:layout_row="0"
                    android:layout_column="2"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
                    android:layout_margin="12dp">
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:padding="16dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:background="#126180"
                        android:id="@+id/layoutCalander">
                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="80dp"
                            android:layout_height="80dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/baseline_calendar"/>
                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Calender"
                            android:textColor="@color/white"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
            </GridLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/layoutGrid"
            android:layout_below="@+id/layoutMission">
            <GridLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:rowCount="1"
                android:columnCount="3"
                android:columnOrderPreserved="false"
                android:alignmentMode="alignMargins">
                <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    android:layout_row="0"
                    android:layout_column="0"
                    app:cardElevation="6dp"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
                    android:layout_margin="12dp">
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:padding="16dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:background="#126180"
                        android:id="@+id/tvBooks">
                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="80dp"
                            android:layout_height="80dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/baseline_library_books"/>
                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Library"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:textColor="@color/white"
                            />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
                <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    android:layout_row="0"
                    android:layout_column="1"
                    app:cardElevation="6dp"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
                    android:layout_margin="12dp">
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:padding="16dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:background="#126180"
                        android:id="@+id/notes">
                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="80dp"
                            android:layout_height="80dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/baseline_notes"/>
                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Notes"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:textColor="@color/white"
                            />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
                <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    android:layout_row="0"
                    android:layout_column="2"
                    app:cardElevation="6dp"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
                    android:layout_margin="12dp">
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:padding="16dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:background="#126180"
                        android:id="@+id/tvPhone">
                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="80dp"
                            android:layout_height="80dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/baseline_call_24"/>
                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Phone"
                            android:textColor="@color/white"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
            </GridLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I have Samsung galaxy s21 fe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try This Code :-**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/space"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/layoutGrid"
    android:background="#000036"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutGrid"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="12dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
            app:cardElevation="6dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tvBooks"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="#126180"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="16dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="80dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="Library"
                    android:textColor="@color/white" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="12dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
            app:cardElevation="6dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/notes"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="#126180"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="16dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="80dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="Notes"
                    android:textColor="@color/white" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="12dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
            app:cardElevation="6dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tvPhone"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="#126180"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="16dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="80dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="Phone"
                    android:textColor="@color/white" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    </LinearLayout>
    
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutMore"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#000036"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="12dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
            app:cardElevation="6dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/layoutSettings"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_row="0"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="#126180"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="16dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="80dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="Settings"
                    android:textColor="@color/white" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="12dp"
            android:background="#000036"
            app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
            app:cardElevation="6dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/layoutReports"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="#000036"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="16dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="80dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="12dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
            app:cardElevation="6dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/layoutCalander"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="#126180"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="16dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="80dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="Calender"
                    android:textColor="@color/white" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]